# Алгоритм оптимизации расстояния между точками в N-мерном пространстве

Tags: оптимизация

Мне нужно оптимизировать расстояние между точками, но нельзя изменять некоторые точки.

Пример(3D):

```
X : входные данные
X[1] = 0.25, 0.8, 0.4 - const
X[2] = 0.11, 0.5, 0.3 - const
X[3] = 0.43, 0.3, 0.1 - mutable(генерируем рандомно 0...1)
X[4] = 0.11, 0.4, 0.2 - mutable(генерируем рандомно 0...1)
X[5] = 0.23, 0.3, 0.3 - mutable(генерируем рандомно 0...1)

dm : Матрица расстояний
0 0.345832 0.393372 0.172916 0.393775
0.345832 0 0.393775 0.172916 0.393372
0.393372 0.393775 0 0.353553 0.707107
0.172916 0.172916 0.353553 0 0.353553
0.393775 0.393372 0.707107 0.353553 0

X : результат
X[1] = 0.25, 0.8, 0.4 - const
X[2] = 0.11, 0.5, 0.3 - const
X[3] = 0.??, 0.?, 0.? - mutable
X[4] = 0.??, 0.?, 0.? - mutable
X[5] = 0.??, 0.?, 0.? - mutable
```

Получается точки X[1] и X[2] уже на своем месте, расстояние между ними равно значению в матрице расстояний, их нельзя изменять. Нужно только изменить {x, y, z} в X[3], X[4], X[5].
Возможно существует алгоритм с помощью которого можно решить данную проблему?

Количество точек ~200

Размерность пространства >= 3D

Comment: А критерий оптимизации-то какой?

Comment: @Akina, dinstance(X[i], X[j]) - dm[i][j] ~= 0

Comment: Это не критерий. По нему все три динамические точки надо поместить в середину отрезка между статическими точками.

Comment: Не понял смысл вашего критерия `dinstance(X[i], X[j]) - dm[i][j] ~= 0`. `dinstance(X[1], X[2]) == 0.345832`, `dm[1][2] == 0.345832`, итого `dinstance(X[1], X[2]) - dm[1][2] == 0.345832 - 0.345832 == 0`. И так для каждой пары точек.

Comment: @wololo, Да, нужно найти такие значения для mutable points, чтобы distance(X[i], X[j]) - dm[i][j] ~=0. То есть distance(X[1], X[5]) ==  0.510294, а нужно как в dm[1][5] == 0.393775. Я раньше использовал MDS для такой задачи, но теперь часть точек const, а MDS изменяет все точки.

Comment: Кажется понял. Матрица расстояний у вас **задана** и нужно подобрать координаты точек так, чтобы матрица расстояний, построенная по этим точкам была максимально похожа на заданную матрицу?

Comment: @wololo, да, все верно.

Comment: Ну тогда это самая обычная оптимизационная задача. И в качестве критерия оптимизации можете объявить, например, минимизацию максимального отклонения расстояния от заданного в матрице. Решать можно любым доступным методом - да хоть покоординатным спуском.

Answer (score 0):

Другими словами, ваша задача формулируется так:

В пространстве размерности D заданы точки X_1, X_2, ..., X_m, задана симметричная матрица L размером NxN, где N > m. Нужно подобрать точки X_{m+1}, ..., X_N так, чтобы соответствующая им матрица расстояний M минимально отличалась от L: |M - L| = min.

Я не буду спрашивать, какую меру в пространстве матриц вы собираетесь использовать для определения расстояния между матрицами, это для решения непринципиально.

Принципиальна размерность задачи. 200 точек - это 200*D параметров. Даже если зафиксированы 100 точек, нахождение остальных равноценно решению оптимизационной задачи в пространстве размерностью 100*N.

Подозреваю, что никакой из прикладных пакетов не сможет решить задачу такой размерности, так как в процессе будут возникать якобианы размером (100*N)x(100*N). Поэтому я бы решал так:

1. Уменьшаем размерность задачи со 100 неизвестных точек до 1. Т.е. берём 100 точек и ищем одну точку, которая даст оптимальную матрицу размером 101 на 101. В качестве метода решения можно взять Монте-Карло, или же решать численно задачу поиска экстремума для функции с D переменными.
2. Зафиксировав 101 точку, ищем 102-ю точку.
3. Зафиксировав 102 точки, ищем 103-ю точку.
   ...
4. Зафиксировав 199 точек, ищем 200 точку.

Стопудов это будет неоптимальное решение. Можно взять его за начальное значение и попробовать уточнить градиентным спуском. В результате вы получите какой-то минимум.

Чутье мне подсказывает, что у этой задачи будет море локальных минимумов, и с практической точки зрения задача поиска глобального минимума будет неразрешима.

Comment: не очень понятно как правильно прикрутить "Монте-Карло". Ок, попробуем так... сгенерировал 'P' точек[0,1] (пусть будет 3D пример), получил 'P' матриц 'M', а дальше как?

Comment: Если вам не горит, я на выходных попробую на scipy сделать градиентный спуск. Идея такая. У вас есть P точек в D мерном пространстве. Их надо объединить в один вектор длиной `D*P`, и использовать как начальное значение для [минимизации](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), в качестве мнимизируемого функционала взять вычисление разницы между матрицей расстояний и заданной матрицей.

Answer (score 0):

Если зафиксированы хотя бы четыре точки (пример для 3D) не в одной плоскости, то координаты остальных восстанавливаются с помощью триангуляции (точно).

Если четырёх точек нет, то однозначного ответа быть не может. К фиксированным точкам надо добавить недостающие до четырёх (несложная задача, координаты дополнительных точек придумываются точно). Если четвёрка оказалась примерно в одной плоскости, то надо выбрать другие дополнительные точки. Отныне считаем всю четверку зафиксированной. Затем триангуляция выше.

После триангуляции запускаем оптимизацию попарных расстояний с помощью МНК. Так как у нас хорошая стартовая точка, МНК должен сойтись быстро.